# Woocommerce - show regular and selling price range

Tags: wordpress

Regular and selling price is shown at simple products (regular price strikethrough) - but at prices with variations theres only the selling price range not the range of the regular price (f.e. 30-49 Euro).

Woocommerce Version 3.09

Comment: Question is not complete. Please provide explaination or add a screenshot.What you expect as result.Have you tried anything?

Comment: The regular price range should also be shown (strikethrough / not crossed out)

Comment: For single product.

Answer (score 0):

Please perform following step :

- Go to product menu edit product
- Product price section
- Remove sale price keep regular price this will not display price with
  strike through.
- update product.

if you want to disable sale price

```
function custom_wc_get_sale_price( $sale_price, $product ) {
return $product->get_regular_price(); 
    return $sale_price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_sale_price', 'custom_wc_get_sale_price', 50, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'custom_wc_get_sale_price', 50, 2 );
```

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding: I want to show the regular price and the selling price for products with variations - theres a price range http://netzlounge.com/single.png (single product ok), http://netzlounge.com/variation.png (no regular price, but it should also be shown)

Comment: all variation have same price?

Comment: If have price with varition then it shows range if you don't want to show then you can write FROM : Min price.I can write that code.